# Sum up all values from a column although they are excluded by a WHERE condition over another column

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=a0f12557f8ae40a8e1c725ac78330eea)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    customerID VARCHAR(255),
    sales_volume INT,
    sales_count VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO sales
(customerID, sales_volume, sales_count
)
VALUES 
("Customer_01", "650", "1"),
("Customer_01", "718", "2"),
("Customer_01", "130", "3"),
("Customer_01", "455", "4"),
("Customer_01", "910", "5"),
("Customer_02", "705", "1"),
("Customer_03", "560", "1"),
("Customer_03", "938", "2"),
("Customer_03", "620", "3"),
("Customer_03", "182", "4"),
("Customer_04", "260", "1"),
("Customer_04", "390", "2");
```

**Expected Result:**

```
customerID      sum(sales_volume)
Customer_01         2863    (=650+718+130+455+910)
Customer_03         2300    (=560+938+620+182)
```

---

In the above result I want to list all customers that have **more than 3 sales** which is defined by the column `sales_count`. 
Therefore, I used the the condition `WHERE sales_count >= 3` in the query.

```
SELECT 
customerID,
sum(sales_volume)
FROM sales
WHERE sales_count >= 3
GROUP BY 1;
```

Based on that query only `Customer_01` and `Customer_03` are listed which is correct. 
However, in the column `sum(sales_volume)` only the `sum` from the **third sale onwards** is displayed.

What do I need to change in my query so for `Cusomter_01` and `Customer_03` **all** their sales are summed up?

Comment: 'more than 3 sales which is defined by the column sales_count.' - apparently not , you seem to want customers where any sale is >=3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `HAVING` clause instead of `WHERE`:

```
SELECT 
customerID,
sum(sales_volume)
FROM sales
GROUP BY 1
HAVING MAX(sales_count) >= 3;
```

The `WHERE` clause filters the table before the aggregation, while the `HAVING` clause filters the results of the aggregation.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=aa6fc9364df9395aa557a90826d896d1).
Results:

```
> customerID  | sum(sales_volume)
> :---------- | ----------------:
> Customer_01 |              2863
> Customer_03 |              2300
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline view method to calculate the sum of volumne:

```
SELECT 
 distinct a.customerID,
(select sum(sales_volume) from sales b where a.customerid = b.customerid group by b.customerid) sales_volume
FROM sales a
WHERE sales_count >= 3;
```